# Return records with common words between them in mysql and rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

please help with this mysql query in rails 3:

In my controller i have:

```
@projects = Project.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

If in my Project table under the "name" column i have the following records:
1). water
2). aquaduct water bridge
3). bridge waterway

If params[:search] = "water", then records 1, 2, 3 are returned. However when params[:search] = "aquaduct water bridge", then record 2 is only returned.

What i need is to search each word(if there are many words in params[:search] string) and return those records found. So for example if params[:search] = "aquaduct water bridge", it must return all records because water is common in all 3 records.

**I am just using water as an example. must apply to any word that is common between records.**

Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this to split the params[:search] and make a query like this:

```
WHERE name LIKE "%aquaduct%" OR name LIKE "%water%" OR  name LIKE "%bridge%"
```

But this is inefficient method.

Try to use MATCH() AND AGAINST() method of mysql for full text searching. Have a look on the link.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Updated:

ALTER TABLE projects ADD FULLTEXT(name);

Comment: @ashish i get the following error(using rails 3):Mysql2::Error: The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Comment: @ashish i get mysql error:  ERROR 1214 (HY000): "The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes" tried this "ALTER TABLE projects ADD FULLTEXT(name);"

Comment: Are you using Myisam??? If not then just change the storage engine of the tabel to MyIsam then it will work

Comment: First change table type by ALTER TABLE projects ENGINE = MYISAM;

Comment: @ashish it works thank you very much, i owe you a beer. Just as a side note, if i use heroku-hosting service for rails apps(which uses postgresql as database) will everything be fine?

Comment: Yes... It will be fine. It needs only mysql

Answer (score 0):

You could split up your target string, and construct a where clause. In the example you give, it would be:

```
WHERE name LIKE "%aquaduct%" OR name LIKE "%water%" OR  name LIKE "%bridge%"
```

Not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer @Ashish's way.. and suggest, if you could use 'scope', your query will be more eligent

cheers

sameera